# SPI Slave MISO Stuck High

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, flash

I'm currently trying to connect a Macronix MX25L6406E SPI flash memory chip to a Raspberry Pi so that I can (hopefully) dump it's memory.

I am using a small Python script to bit-bang the commands and read data from the chip, an approach the worked for a previously used Winbond chip. My problem, is that the chip seems to be holding the MISO line high which is causing the Raspberry Pi to read in 1's (0xFF bytes).

I have confirmed that the pins of the chip are all connected to the correct GPIO pins on the Pi, and that the Vcc voltage to the chip is correct (3.3V).

Also, if it helps, the Pi isn't holding the MISO line high, as the LED I've attached to the line remains illuminated after disconnecting the Pi, but reconfiguring the corresponding GPIO pin as an output and setting it LOW seems to cause the MISO line to drop LOW.

The pin states during the transactions are as follows: MOSI: 1 0 0 1, MISO: 1 1 1 1, CS: 0 0 0 0. That's the first nybble of the Read ID commands (0x9F). Then, this is the first nybble of the response: MOSI: 1 1 1 1, MISO: 1 1 1 1, CS: 0 0 0 0.

Comment: What speed is your clock? I would avoid attaching other components like LEDs to your data lines... 

Also, that chip is not designed to source power (on the order of mA) on its output pins. Can you give us a circuit diagram?

Comment: Like I said originally, I'm bit-banging the data so my clock speed is currently 2Hz. I've slowed it to that speed so I can actually see the data (on the LED's). Previously, it was running at about ~5KHz (which worked fine for the Winbond chip). I'll see if I can get a circuit diagram...

Comment: Well that is odd, because when the MISO is inactive it's high impedance, so the LED should be out. This means that it's sending data. Are you sure that all your connections are correct (especially gnd) and that you're sending the right commands? Can you list out the LED sequence that you observe during a transaction, with CS, MISO,MOSI and SCK?

Comment: Here is a GIF of the transaction: https://imgur.com/a/k63TV. The LED's are as follows; Top Left: CS, Bottom Left: MISO, Top Right: SCK, Bottom Right: MOSI. Sorry for the poor image quality and the lens flare, white LED's were all I had.

Comment: That's pretty confusing, can you just list the LED states on each rising edge of the clock? i.e. 

MISO:  1 0 0
 
MOSI:  1 0 0

CS:   1 0 0 

etc

Comment: Do you have a falling edge on the CS?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you edit this information into your question, not in comments. Otherwise, you're expecting people to piece it all together in their head. Please can you add a circuit diagram to your question for the same reason. The schematic editor there is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @BeB00 Yes, I probably should have mentioned that. SCK has both a rising and a falling edge.

Comment: Are your hold pin(s) set to their proper levels, and are you following the requirements on page 30 (section 11) on the datasheet?

Comment: Yes, the hold pin is tied to VCC, The CS line didn't go low during power-up and no data was sent until quite some time after power-up (the Pi was booting). Should I try adding a pullup to CS?

Comment: Yes, do you have a logic analyzer or oscilloscope? The problem is that your current setup can't detect noise or glitches that are too fast for the eye to see, but will affect the communication

Comment: No, I don't have a logic analyser or an oscilloscope. I do not believe my problem is one of interference since this exact setup worked with a counterpart SPI flash chip. That chip however, did not have it's MISO line stuck high and sent usable data. Why could this one have a problem with only ONE pin?